# obout grid add,edit,delete records from client side

Tags: asp.net, ajax, obout

I am trying to make the operations of Update, Delete and Add only on the client-side, without any post backing.through grid.after editing data in grid i need to save the data to data base

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it via many ways depends on your requirement. one of the way is to put a button outside the grid for Insert / UPDATE options or use SAVE method of Grid itself. For save method you can find a  'OnInsertCommand' which can create an event on server side where you can manage all the db insertions.
Let me know if you still have problem in it.